# placing two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I have two divs one is a picture and the other is text.  I am putting these two divs inside a parent div and using as my header.  My image is much taller than the text.  What I want to do is put the image all the way on the left and the text on the right vertically aligned at the bottom to align with the images bottom.  I am having a hard time doing this.  Also, I can't use float because when I view the page on a mobile phone because of the width the text breaks to the next line which is fine but using float:right it goes to the right which is not what I want here is what I am trying.

```
<div id="header" style="overflow:auto"><div style="float:left;">

<img src="Images/crescentlogo.png" /></div>

<div><h4 class="gold">Daily <span class="DarkGreen">EXCEEDING</span> <span class="gold">our Customers'</span> <span class="DarkGreen">EXPECTATIONS</span></h4></div>

</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: You want to put the text on the right, but when the text "goes to the right", it's something you don't want?  And you want the text "vertically aligned at the bottom to align with the images bottom", but when it "breaks to the next line" it's fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<style>
    h4{
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body><div id="header">
<img src="Images/crescentlogo.png" id="img" />

<div id="text" style="display: inline;"><h4 class="gold">Daily <span    
class="DarkGreen">EXCEEDING</span>
    <span class="gold">our Customers'</span> <span class="DarkGreen">EXPECTATIONS</span></h4>    </div>

</div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Link for JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5wCG/1/

Comment: that looks like it worked however I can't get it to go to the bottom.

Comment: What do you need it to be now ..?

Answer (score 0):

Give `float:left` to `img` and also give `float:left` to `div`, it will place side by side

```
img div {
    float:left; }
```

Comment: that does not change anything.